# How to create/edit files for a nologin user in RHEL/CentOS?

Tags: permissions, centos, login, file-permissions, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have a user defined like so:

```
sudo useradd -m -s /sbin/nologin foo
```

It is not meant to be logged into but it is meant to serve a web application. However, if I try to do anything inside the directory...

```
sudo -u foo -H touch bar
```

I receive an error.

```
touch: cannot touch ‘bar’: Permission denied
```

My question is: what am I doing wrong? That is, if it is possible, what should I do to control a user's home directory without the need to log in?

Answer (score 1):

> sudo -u foo -H touch bar

You're trying to assume the account of the foo user, who does not have login access (specifically, a shell).  That won't work  :-)

You could either control the user's home directory as root. e.g.

```
sudo touch /home/foo/bar
sudo chown foo.foo /home/foo/bar
```

To achieve what you want, or if you can, `su` to root and do it, or;

You could do a one-time override of the shell for the foo user

```
su -s /bin/bash foo
```

To get you to a bash shell running as the foo user, and make your changes there.  Which is what you're probably wanting to do in the first place.

Note:

A user with /sbin/nologin is generally a system account.  System accounts are supposed to be managed by the root user, or a user with sudo privileges (A member of the wheel group in recent versions of RHEL/CentOS).
I gave you method one first, because that's generally the way it's done, not the way you're going about it.  That's not to say you're doing it the wrong way - there's always more than one :-)

Comment: Hmm. That all makes sense. I switched the user over to bash. However, I still get permission issues. Using sudo as the current user works, though. And there are certainly other ways of doing this. I recall once getting away with some automated behavior using a git user. :D

Comment: I'll ask the obvious then - You've checked the owner/group of /home/foo and it's foo.foo?  Then file permissions?  drwvrwx---?

Comment: Those are exactly the permissions.

Comment: What version of CentOS or RHEL are you running?  Works fine for me in V7.

Comment: I must be overlooking something because I am running RHEL 7.

Comment: Found it (Sort of)! Apparently, the `-H` flag is defaulting to the current directory, which is inside the sudoer's home. It is my understanding that this flag is supposed to point to the target user's  home. I am not sure why its not doing that.